# Angular-Router: Wordpress in sub directory of Angular Application

Tags: angular, wordpress, .htaccess

I am running an Angular application in the root directory of an Apache web-server. This application uses the Angular router module and serves as a client for API calls. In a sub directory of root (named "wordpress") I am running a Wordpress installation. This Wordpress installation serves as the back-end / API for the client described above.

The API calls work perfectly fine. My Problem is as follows:
When I try to access the sub directory by "www.mydomain.com/wordpress" the router module kicks in and redirects to the default route and so loads the Angular App.

When I access wordpress by a specific url (including .php extension) wordpress gets loaded perfectly fine (example "www.mydomain.com/wordpress/wp-login.php"). I would like to load wordpress on any routes under "www.mydomain.com/wordpress/". Any Idea on how I could make this work?

Comment: Can you provide your .htaccess in your root and in your /wordpress/ directories? It looks like the redirect in your root needs to exclude the wordpress directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am also utilizing Angular as a front-end using a plugin of mine, [Xo for Angular](https://angularxo.io/), which provides an integrated approach to loading an Angular App as if it were a normal theme within WordPress.

You likely need to add the `--deploy-url` flag to your `ng build` or `ng serve` command.

```
ng build --deploy-url /wordpress/
```

Hopefully that helps!